# Ejecutar autoclick en segundo plano

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Quería ejecutar un autoclick pero sólo me funcionaba con la terminal maximizada, cuando estaba minimizada al apretar f1 no respondía los click estuve leyendo un post sobre ejecución en segundo plano pero no entendí como podía hacerlo aquí está el script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
while true; do 
read -sn3 key 
if [ "$key" = "$(tput kf1) " ]; then
 xdotool click 1 
 xdotool click 1 
 xdotool click 1 

fi 
done
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo funcionar?

también quiero saber como `(tput kf1)` lo modifico al click izquierdo

Answer (score 0):

Con relación a este problema :

> ***cuando estaba minimizada al apretar f1 no respondía***

podrias hacer algo asi:

```
$ ./script &
           ^--- ejecutar script en segundo plano desde el principio
```

[autor de esta respuesta:marc-b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)

Una alternativa a esto, que encontré  es escribir una función

```
Foo(){
Do stuff
}
```

y llamar a la función y enviarla al fondo

```
Foo &
```

Todo **dentro del script**, para que no tengas que hacer

```
script.sh &
```

En cambio, solo al invocar el script lo enviará a segundo plano.

[Autor de esta respuesta : tejaswi-prakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7832412/tejaswi-prakash)

fuente : [automatically running a bash script in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732129/automatically-running-a-bash-script-in-the-background)

Comment: Con ./script & no hace absolutamente nada ni maximizada ni minimizada, la funcion Foo tampoco me sirve sólo me devuelve 
^[OQ al presionar f2 con la terminal maximizada